# Check class type

Tags: java

How i can check if a class is of a determinated type for example:

```
// PacketHandler.java

public interface PacketHandler<T> {
    public void handlePacket(T packet);
}


// PacketReader.java

public void read() {
    Packet packet = // Read some input
    for(PacketHandler packetHandler : packetHandlers) {
        if  (packetHandler is the type of packet) { // here is the problem
            packetHandler.handlePacket(packet);
        }
    }
}

public void registerHandler(PacketHandler<?> packetHandler) {
    packetHandlers.add(packetHandler);
}

// Main

packetReader.registerHandler(new PacketHandler<RandomPacket>() {
    public void handlePacket(RandomPacket packet) {
        // I handle the packet
    }
});
```

I know that this question maybe seems stupid;
but how to solve this problem?

****Edit*******

Jon Skeet, so the class should be:

```
public class RandomClass implements PacketHandler {
    public boolean handlePacket(Packet packet) {
       if (packet instanceof PacketThatThisClassHandle) {
          //handle with casting
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is the problem that you want to see if it's a `PacketHandler<T1>` for some `T1`, _as opposed to_ `PacketHandler<T2>` for some other type parameter?

Comment: I have to check if the type of PacketHandler<T> is an instance of some Packet

Comment: What do you mean "some Packet"?  It looks like `Packet` is a non-generic class, so an object is either an instance of `Packet` or not.  Do you mean some subclass of `Packet`?  Are there going to be types that say `extends Packet implements PacketHandler<X>`?  I'm confused about what you're looking for.

Comment: I have an abstract class Packet after i have the class that extends Packet, for example RandomPacket, OtherRandomPacket, now when i read a stream i have to call the interface that have type of the packet readed

Comment: OK, so you've got a `PacketHandler<T>` and you want to test whether `T` is a particular class.  (This isn't the same as testing whether the `PacketHandler<T>` is an instance of a particular class.  Your comment was confusing.)  This is a problem because of type erasure; see the other answers for ideas.

Comment: @abj Yes you have described perfectly my problem, Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Java generics use [*type erasure*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure), meaning that at execution time, any particular `PacketHandler<T>` is just `PacketHandler` as far as the VM is concerned.

You may want to change your code to:

```
public interface PacketHandler {
    // The parameter type can  be Object if you really want
    boolean tryHandlePacket(Packet packet);
}
```

... and make a `PacketHandler` just return `false` if it doesn't know how to handle a particular packet type.

Then you can just use:

```
for (PacketHandler handler : handlers) {
    if (handler.tryHandlePacket(packet)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

(That's assuming you only want a single handler to actually handle any packet type.)

If you still want a generic interface, you'd either need a `boolean handlesPacket(Packet)` method, or possibly a `Class<T> getPacketType()` method. Either way it's still going to be a pain in terms of casting the packet to the right type...

If you have lots of packet handlers, you could potentially create an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPacketHandler<T extends Packet>
    implements PacketHandler {

    private final Class<T> packetType;

    protected AbstractPacketHandler(Class<T> packetType) {
        this.packetType = packetType;
    }

    protected abstract void handlePacket(T packet);

    public boolean tryHandlePacket(Packet packet) {
        if (!packetType.isInstance(packet)) {
            return false;
        }
        handlePacket(packetType.cast(packet));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public class FooPacketHandler extends PacketHandler<Foo> {
    public FooPacketHandler() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    protected void handlePacket(Foo packet) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So the class that have to implements PacketHandle should be: *read up*

Comment: @Emax: Yes, that would work. It's all a bit ugly, but that's the nature of the sort of dynamic handling you're dealing with.

Comment: @Emax: I've added some extra details about how you can make the handler *implementations* use generics, but maintain a non-generic client interface - that might make things simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Type erasure won't make this attempt easy. The mapping part it's quite easy, you can use a `HashMap`. But the problem is that the `handlePacket` method accepts a parameter of type `T`, which forces you to cast the object to that type before passing it to the handler.

To avoid relaxing the constraint you could use a two level invokation, something like:

```
  interface Packet { }
  class ConcretePacket implements Packet { }

  HashMap<Class<?>, PacketHandler<?>> mapping = 
                new HashMap<Class<?>, PacketHandler<?>>();

  public abstract class PacketHandler<T extends Packet> {        
    PacketHandler(Class<T> clazz) {
      mapping.put(clazz, this);
    }

    public final void handlePacket(Packet packet) {
      doHandlePacket((T)packet);
    }

    public abstract void doHandlePacket(T packet);
  }

  public class ConcretePacketHandler extends PacketHandler<ConcretePacket>
  {
    ConcretePacketHandler()
    {
      super(ConcretePacket.class);
    }

    public void doHandlePacket(ConcretePacket s) {
      // whatever
    }
  }

  public void receivedPacket(Packet packet) {
    PacketHandler<?> handler = mapping.get(packet.getClass());
    if (handler != null)
      handler.handlePacket(packet);
  }
```

Mind that this could not work in certain situations (maybe with different classloaders involved) and that, to manage subclasses of `PacketManager`, you will need to find a better way to retrieve the correct handler, eg by using a `List<Pair<Class<?>,PacketHandler<?>>>` so that you can check

```
if (listElement.clazz.isAssignableFrom(packet.getClass()))
  handler = listElement.handler;
```

maybe even using priorities so that the exact class is found before a possible superclass.

Comment: Don't forget the possibility of a handler which can cope with a superclass of the given packet...

Comment: @JonSkeet: that's a further requirement which can be solved by using a different mapping scheme. I edited the answer to include this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to get but you could possibly use:

```
if ( type.isInstance(obj) ) {
    //do something
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: That isn't what he wants, but it took some work to make that clear.  See above comments.

Comment: Alright, but this may help someone else with a similar question but thanks for letting me know.